# How to pass the language value to url for translate in android studio

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, spinner, translation

how can i pass the Value of the "key" here to url

I want to pass the value of language in this code below to url, where by if user select Arabic, the value of arabic "ar" should be send to url...... how can i write the code to pass dis value

i have used HAshmap to setup my spinner to display the language names.

below is my activity code

Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

```
    Map<String, String> flanguages = new HashMap<String, String>();
    flanguages.put("Arabic", "ar");
    flanguages.put("English", "en");
    flanguages.put("French", "fr");
    flanguages.put("Hausa", "ha");
    flanguages.put("Igbo", "ig");
    flanguages.put("Yoruba", "yo");

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(flanguages.keySet());


    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```